# Make query which extracts missing numbers from certain intervals. MS Access

Tags: ms-access, numbers, sequential

Is it possible to make query that will extract numbers which are not in certain interval of sequential numbers. 
For example: Let's said that the interval of sequential numbers is 950 to 960. I have SELECT query with following numbers in "Field1": 950, 955, 956, 959.
The requested query should return in a field 951, 952, 953, 954, 957, 958, 960.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding, but..

SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE Numbers NOT IN ('950', '951')

Comment: The problem is that first I have to create a query that will return the certain interval of sequential numbers. The interval (From X to Y) is defined in a Textboxes in a form. Then combine two queries in one.Here is what I have so far:SELECT  [num] FROM Query44
WHERE (((Query44.num) Not In (SELECT Field1 FROM [Query2])))
ORDER BY Query44.num; The question is how to create Query44 that will contain sequential numbers in interval defined in Textboxes in a Form.